# powershell use-azurehdinsightCluster specified method not suppored

Tags: powershell

Hi I am new to azure and trying to run script job on my cluster; yesterday i was able to to do map reduce streaming job successfully; however today i am stuck when trying to do hive job ; on powershell ise  when i type command use-azurehdinsightcluster 'nnn' I am getting specified method not supported
also when i try script file I get error  start-azure job  not supported...
I I have  mysettings.publishsettings file imported and in place. I have azure.psd1 
I am connected to azure etc...
one thing confuses me: account name there are three account names:  xxxxx@hotmail.com; and one which is similar to my storage account name , and one weird pay-as-you-go
I have tried all of them
I am totally confused please can some one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to the latest powershell from http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/install-configure-powershell/#Install and try again.